# Splitting a string powershell version 4?

Tags: powershell

this is part of my bigger code.

I have not added any assemblies for this. I want to get '20161207' separately in a different variable. This approach however is failing with: "parsing "*" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing."

```
[string]$filter = '20161207*'
$pathPart = $filter -split '*'

echo $pathPart[0]
```

please help. I am using powershell version 4.0.
I am not sure what is the escape character in my version of powershell. i Have tried '/'
I want to echo out: '20161207'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-split` operator uses regular expressions, not literal strings. Since `*` is a *quantifier* in regexes what you got there is invalid. You need to escape it:

```
$filter -split '\*'
```

or use the `string.Split` method instead:

```
$filter.Split('*')
```

which splits on single characters.

Comment: This method produces '20161207 ' and not '20161207'. there is a space at the end which i am not interested in.

Comment: @RiteshThakur then call `Trim` on output to remove whitespaces

Comment: @RiteshThakur: The space should only appear if you are converting the resulting array back into a string (which in your case would join the first part and the empty string with a space in between), _or_ if you have a space before the split character. Splitting alone won't magically generate spaces, but your other code might.